# How can maven be set to require no target for the `mvn` command?

Tags: java, maven-2, build

I'm trying to set up a Maven project so that it will build upon receiving the `mvn` command at the command line without any target such as `install` or `package`.

This might seem a strange goal, but I'm guessing that it is the simplest way to fit a new project into an existing architecture.

I've been looking at some old `pom.xml` files, in an effort to find how this is being defined, with no luck so far. (And too much is different for me to simply copy an old `pom`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the `<defaultGoal>` element. It's part of the [BaseBuild Element Set](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element).

The value of the `<defaultGoal>` element can be either a goal or a life-cycle phase. So for example, if I add this to my pom:

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
</build>
```

Then I can invoke the `mvn` command with no arguments and the life-cycle as far as the `package` phase will be run (as if I had invoked `mvn package`).

Comment: Hmm... it seems that something more complicated is going on in my case, as this never appears. I may ask another question.